# Android Programming...How do I load contact photos so I can use them in an app?

Tags: android, contacts

I am trying to simply load just the contact photo of all my contacts and display them in a gallery.widget...Do I create a query? I was trying simply just to do People.loadcontactphoto but was getting errors....Any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html)? You could use [`loadContactPhoto`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Contacts.People.html) in the [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) method and make sure [`getDropDownView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) calls [`getView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html).  This should get the job done by loading the default view with the image from the contact.

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getView(int position, View row, ViewGroup parent) {
    //loadContactPhoto
    //set the view image to be the contact photo
    //...

    //This is an over simplification of the method
    //a custom layout may need to be inflated.

    return row;
}
```